# swift calling a func from inside static func?

Tags: swift

I am trying to call upon func to bring up an alert and it is inside another static func though it's not working

inside my fetch user func when actual longitude return nil i want to call the alert func though its not working as i thought it would

it says error: extra argument in call "message

```
func alertTheUser(title: String , message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
    alert.addAction(ok);
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
}

static func firestorefetchUserWithUID(uid: String, completion:@escaping (User2) -> ()) {
   //code taken out for this example
   //fetch user from database
   //dictionary = snapshot etc
   guard let latitude = dictionary["Actual Latitude"] as? String else {
       alertTheUser(title:"title" , message:"message")
       return 
   }
   //code taken out for this example
}
```

Comment: Please take time to format correctly.

Comment: You have to understand that instance functions operate on instances. You don't have an instance, so you have nothing for an instance function to operate on.

Comment: This is not related to the question asked but could help provide a solution to your real problem. These two functions do not look like they belong in the same class.  The alertTheUser function should be in a view controller and the firestore function should be in a model class.

Answer (score 3):

A static func cannot call a non-static func directly. A non-static func is an *instance* method, and in a static func there is *no instance* — it is static, meaning it belongs to the *type*, not to an *instance* of the type.

Thus, static `firestorefetchUserWithUID` cannot call `alertTheUser` because `alertTheUser` is an instance method and you have no instance to send it to. And if `alertTheUser` *were* static, you'd have the same problem again, because then it could not call `present` for the same reason, as `present` is an instance method.

It looks to me like making the static func static was just a mistake to begin with; make it an instance method, if you know you'll always have an instance to send it to.  (And I presume you *do* have an instance, because your use of `present` suggests that this code must be in a UIViewController subclass.)